# DotNetOpenAuth.... what is?

Tags: web-applications, authentication, dotnetopenauth, administration

I'm not sure what it is and what is DotNetOpenAuth. Can you explain it  in few words? 
I am investigating about the management of users in a web application (asp.net mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [www.dotnetopenauth.net](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/):

> DotNetOpenAuth is a well established open source library that bring OpenID, OAuth, and ICard capabilities to the Microsoft .NET Framework.

So:

A .NET library, that is open source and which implements [OpenID](http://openid.net/), [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) and [ICard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Card). OpenID is the login mechanism used on StackOverflow, OAuth is a similar one as is ICard.

Comment: you think, is it convenient to use this? what are the biggest advantages to be gained?

Comment: @GgSalent - That's a very different question from the one you asked and that I have answered. I suggest you ask this as a new question.